# How can move between the forms pages in Delphi using DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a question about a DBLookupComboBox component in Delphi. I want to move between the forms pages in the Delphi program using a DBLookupComboBox component.

When I choose a name "ahmed" for example from the DBLookupComboBox list it will move to form 4, and when I choose a name "fatima" from a DBLookupComboBox list it will move to form 5, as shown in image below.

What is the appropriate code for this operation in Delphi?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to move between the forms pages". Do you mean you have a lot of forms, mostly invisible and want to make one of them visible when the user clicks in a DBLookupComboBox, and hide the form with the DBLookupComboBox? Also, clarify how you associate "ahmed" with form4 and "fatima" with Form5. Do you have a list of those associations? Are Form4 and Form5 already created or do you want to create it on the fly? What happens when the user is done with Form4 or Form5? As you see, you must give more information about your design so that you can get good answer.

Comment: hi fpiette ,yes i have a lot of forms, mostly invisible and want to make one of them visible when the user clicks in a DBLookupComboBox and i have list of 'n' name  in DBLookupComboBox and i have 'n' form , i want to when the user clicks on a name from this list, a form should appear

Comment: It seems odd to be using a database at all under these circumstances. Still, the obvious answer is to use the OnClick event.

Comment: @BenshasarAl OK, I understand you still have no link between the N forms and the N names. You may use a TDictionary for the purpose. Please confirm.

Comment: Dsm, OnClick event. is work only with combobox or dBcombobox by select the items index but not work in DBLookupComboBox that because there is no ItemIndex int DBLookupComboBox

Comment: Tom Brunberg , for example we have 5 name in the list of dBcombobox and 5 forms when the user click in the 'name 1' the 'form1' should appear and  when the user click in the 'name 2' the 'form2' should appear ,........, This is what I want to do.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood something in your post, so I deleted my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code to do what you asked. In this code, I use a TClientDataset to stored data to populate the TComboBox. Of course you may use the dataset you like. Note that I used a TCombobox and not a DBLookupCombobox. I think it is better.

I used a TDictionary to link names and forms. The forms must be added to the project and auto-created. I created two forms in two units: UnitAhmed and UnitMohamed. These are just empty forms renamed and saved in their unit.

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, Vcl.DBCtrls,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  UnitAhmedForm,
  UnitMohamedForm;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ClientDataSet1 : TClientDataset;
    FDictionary : TDictionary<String, TForm>;
    procedure SelectedFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.ComboBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    SelectedForm : TForm;
begin
    // Try to find the name selected in the combobox and the associated form
    if not FDictionary.TryGetValue(ComboBox1.Text, SelectedForm) then begin
        ShowMessage('Not found');
        Exit;
    end;
    // The name and form are found, make it visible
    SelectedForm.Visible := TRUE;
    // Assign an OnClose event to make mainform visible when the selected
    // form is closed
    SelectedForm.OnClose := SelectedFormClose;
    // Hide the main form
    Visible              := FALSE;
end;

procedure TMainForm.SelectedFormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    // Make the main form visible
    Visible := TRUE;
end;


procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Create an in-memory dataset with one single field
    ClientDataSet1 := TClientDataset.Create(Self);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Name', ftString, 32);
    ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'Name';
    ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;

    // Populate the dataset with two records
    ClientDataSet1.Open;
    ClientDataSet1.Append;
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'ahmed';
    ClientDataSet1.Post;
    ClientDataSet1.Append;
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'mohamed';
    ClientDataSet1.Post;

    // Fill the combobox with the just created dataset content
    ClientDataSet1.First;
    while not ClientDataSet1.Eof do begin
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
        ClientDataSet1.Next;
    end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FreeandNil(FDictionary);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // Create the dictionary which associate a name and a form.
    // We cannot do that in the FormCreate because at that time the other
    // forms are not created yet (By auto-create mechanism)
    // Here in the OnShow event handler, all forms are already created
    FDictionary := TDictionary<String, TForm>.Create;
    FDictionary.Add('ahmed',   AhmedForm);
    FDictionary.Add('mohamed', MohamedForm);
end;

end.
```

Comment: fpiette, Can you put the project file link

Comment: The `TDBLookupComboBox` has `OnClick` event handler too.

Comment: Ilyes , but i dont have the ItemsIndex to select the list in TDBLookupComboBox

Comment: i think if we have table with 2 fields (id,Name) we can use the DBLookUpComboBox1.KeyField to select the name But I do not know how???

Comment: @BenshasarAl just copy the source code in a form you create with just a single TCombobox. Name the file Unit6 (As I have) and the form MainForm.

Comment: I solved the problem Thank you very much fpiette